# ¿Para que sirve asignar un tamaño inicial a un archivo primario?

Tags: sql-server

¿Porque se debe asignar un `SIZE=Tamaño` para un archivo primario(al momento de crear la base de datos), si de todos modos este podría estar vacío o bien su tamaño dependería de los datos que tiene?

Si hago un `SIZE=50MB` no significa que el archivo tenga 50MB en ese momento, no comprendo muy bien porque hay que asignar ese espacio

¿Para que hay que darle un tamaño inicial a un archivo que inicialmente no tiene tamaño? ¿de que sirve establecer un `SIZE`o `SIZEGROWTH`?

¿Porque hay que establecer esos limites?, ¿Que hace sql server con ellos?

Answer (score 2):

Hola Alfredo Espinoza:

.- No se tiene porque elegir un tamaño inicial para la base de datos en el momento de la creación. Es un parámetro por defecto. Si lo utilizas, se creará con tús especificaciones.

> Cuando no se suministra size para el archivo principal, Motor de base
>   de datos utiliza el tamaño del archivo principal de la base de datos
>   modelo. El tamaño predeterminado del modelo es de 8 MB (a partir de
>   SQL Server 2016 (13.x)) o 1 MB (para versiones anteriores). Cuando se
>   especifica un archivo de datos secundario o un archivo de registro,
>   pero no se especifica size para el archivo, Motor de base de datos
>   hace que el tamaño del archivo sea de 8 MB (a partir de SQL Server
>   2016 (13.x)) o 1 MB (para versiones anteriores). El tamaño
>   especificado para el archivo principal debe tener al menos el tamaño
>   del archivo principal de la base de datos model.

Si hago un SIZE=50MB no significa que el archivo tenga 50MB en ese momento, no comprendo muy bien porque hay que asignar ese espacio

.- El motor en el momento de la creación de la base de datos, solicita al SO., el tamaño que le has indicado, y reserva ese espacio en los archivos mdf y ldf. No quiere decir que estén llenos, sino reservados, para las operaciones que le correspondan.

```
CREATE DATABASE [miNuevaBBDD]
CONTAINMENT = NONE
ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'miNuevaBBDD', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL  Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\miNuevaBBDD.mdf' , SIZE = 51200KB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'miNuevaBBDD_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL  Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\miNuevaBBDD_log.ldf' , SIZE = 8192KB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
GO
```

[image: Tamaño real de los archivos = al especificado]

Realmente lo importante no es que hace con ellos, sino que hace cuando no tiene ese espacio reservado. Cuando tu solicitas una sentencia cualquiera de SQL, bien sea mediante código, o desde el cliente, realmente como todo gestor de base de datos, tiene que anotar primero la sentencia en el/los archivos de log, y una vez este confirmada tiene que anotarla en el/los archivos de datos. Cuando al escribir en disco no tiene espacio suficiente para hacerlo, el motor tiene que disponer de más espacio, y le solicita al sistema operativo, un "trozo" mayor de espacio para el o los archivos que correspondan. Esto es una demora de tiempo, que perjudica en rendimiento.

La solución, es tener espacio reservado de manera que sus peticiones de crecimiento se vean limitadas para no penalizar las transacciones.

[Create Database](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Espero te ayude